# Why hidden fields will always be null inside my ItemUpdated Event receiver , if i checked them using properties.AfterProperties

Tags: 2013, development, event-receivers, farm-solution

I am working on a SharePoint 2013 on-premises farm. and i have added an ItemUpdated event receiver for my custom list, as follow:-

```
public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            base.ItemUpdated(properties);
            var abcd = properties.AfterProperties["OrderInternalStage2"];
            var abcd2 = properties.ListItem["OrderInternalStage2"];
```

now in my case the `OrderInternalStage2` is a hidden field inside the content type. And if i check the value using `properties.ListItem["OrderInternalStage2"]` the value will be correct, but inside the `properties.AfterProperties["OrderInternalStage2"];` the value will always be null??? now if i change the field from being hidden to optional, then the value will be presented inside the `properties.AfterProperties["OrderInternalStage2"];` .. so i am not sure what is the reason behind this behavioure, why hidden fields will be null inside the `AfterProperties` for the Itemupdated event recevier ??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason if a hidden column has a default value and when you hit save it saves it by default. In an event receiver when you hit save `afterproperties` is responsible to show 'newly changed' value which is `NULL` correct behaviour when the column is `hidden`.

> **Reference** [Before vs After properties](http://srisharepointdevelopment.blogspot.in/2013/06/beforeproperties-and-afterproperties-in.html) and [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms463479.aspx)

Comment: @little_bi_thoughts but in my case the hidden field does not have a defualt value, where i am controlling its value inside my ER code. but i can capture its value using `properties.ListItem["OrderInternalStage2"]` correctly, but if i try to capture its value using `properties.AfterProperties["OrderInternalStage2"];` it will always be null.. also when i submit a new or edit form the `properties.AfterProperties` will show all the fields values (not just the updated ones) and in the ItemUpdated case the current and after properties should always be the same..

Comment: .. but for hidden fields they will be null in the After case.. which is i am asking why ?